# How to switch to another user

Tags: users

I created another user in CentOs named sheilay. From the default account which is root, how can I use the user sheilay in the CLI without shutting it down? What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `root` account for all and sundry purposes? This is not a recommended practice; furthermore it can be outright dangerous.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something...but after you created the user why not just logout and login as the new user?  Or did you mean you didn't want to leave your current terminal (that is, you actually meant logout, not shutdown)?

Answer (score 3):

```
su - sheilay
```

This will prompt you for password of user sheilay.

For more reading about `su` read [me](http://man.he.net/man1/su) or just type `man su` and then enter

**UPDATE :** If you run `su` as root, it will not prompt you for a password. If you want to exit from that user session, just type `exit` and enter

Comment: As root, it shouldn't ask for the password.